# Automate sending a request and saving the response

Tags: jmeter, postman, fiddler, charles-proxy, burp

There is a URL which I want to hit and save the response. The URL id needs to be incremented each time and save the response. For example -

First Get Request - http://google.com/getdata/?**Id=1**

First Response - one

Second Request - http://google.com/getdata/?**Id=2**

Second Response - two

and so on...

I want to hit the request with increment the id each time and save the response

I have tried using fiddler but unable to figure how to increment the id and save the response.

P.S. - I have to make around 6,00,000 hits

Comment: which scripting language are you planning to use  ?

Comment: Can you ellaborate how you want to save responses?

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler:

Open script editor (Control + r ) then add the following code inside **OnBeforeResponse**

```
 static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
        if(oSession.oRequest["X-SAVE-ME"] != "")
        {
            oSession.SaveResponseBody("C:\\tempfiddler\\" + oSession.SuggestedFilename);
        }

    }
```

Go to the "Composer" tab and include the header X-SAVE-ME with any value, in the URL, replace your **ID** with **#** (just like this: http://google.com/getdata/?Id=#) fiddler will now ask for the starting and ending value of ID before executing;

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter you need to click , Ctrl+0 and Ctrl+1 to create , Thread Group and [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

In Thread Group put the number of hits you need in `Number of Threads (users)`

In HTTP Request Put in `Server Name or IP` www.google.com and in `Path` /getdata/?Id=${__threadNum}

[__threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) will create increasing number from thread 1 to number of hits.

For small number of hits or debugging you can add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to view request/response by clicking Ctrl+9 in Test Plan/Thread Group level.

To save the response use Post Processor, especially by adding [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) below HTTP Request by clicking Ctrl+2.

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using a Perl-type regular expression. As a post-processor, this element will execute after each Sample request in its scope, applying the regular expression, extracting the requested values, generate the template string, and store the result into the given variable name.

Import to notice that for [load testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running) you need to work with non GUI mode, which means call jmeter using command line as `jmeter -n -t myTest.jmx`

> you will use Command-line mode (called Non-GUI mode) to run it for the Load Test.
>   Don't run load test using GUI mode !

For saving all responses to a one file see [save response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896087/headless-jmeter-how-to-get-printed-the-response-data-in-the-output-file) or if you want to save file per thread/user you can add [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am unable to understand the process of saving response. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Karma5 Added more details about saving responses

Answer (score 1):

Since the 'Postman' tag is mentioned, I can help you regarding how to implement this in Postman.
Postman has a nice feature of using 'variables'.

You can use environment variables or globals.

Read more about these on their docs: 
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

You can use a global variable such as 'counter' and set it to 1 / whatever starting point you want.
Then you can modify your request like so :
`http://google.com/getdata/?Id={{iteration}}`

Now, in the **Tests** script of the request you can write the following script

`let i = parseInt(pm.globals.get('iteration')) + 1;
 pm.globals.set('iteration', i);`

Also, to access the response you can use the following command in **Test** script:
`console.log(pm.response); // Use pm.response as per your needs`

Save the request in a collection.
Now load the Postman's Runner and select the collection.
Now you can put an iteration count of 6,00,000 and hit run!

Remember, heavy iterations will cause performance degradation.

Comment: I am getting an error,"The request does not have any tests"

Comment: That is not an error. The runner shows that you've not setup any tests. However, if you've written a console.log inside the requests then 1). Launch the Postman Console (View > Postman Console) 2). Now run the collection using runner. You'll see your responses logged in the console.

Comment: The issue is it is showing {{iteration}} as unresolved variable, Variable is not defined in the current environment

Comment: Ohh, did you setup an environment and then put a variable 'iteration' inside that ? 
When you're using the runner you need to select the 'Environment' from the dropdown - it's just above the iterations box on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the snapshot below for your scenario.

[Scenario_Testplan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdq7f.png)

First, go to user properties and put "sample_variables = ID, Response_File_Name" or whatever the name you choose for the variables. Restart jmeter.
Create the below plan:-

1. CSV data set config to have incremental values and response file name
2. HTTP request will use ${ID}
3. Save response to a file will use ${Response_File_Name}

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by command line, using a while loop with a curl to the URL, storing the body result on the standard output to a file. It would look something like this:

```
for i in {1..600000}; do curl "http://google.com/getdata/?id=$i" > body-result-id-$i; done
```

I couldn't test the line above because I don't have any access to a console right now, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Burp you can do this using the Intruder tool. First, capture a sample request in Burp. If you're unsure how to do this, please consult the [getting started](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1816883-getting-started-with-burp-suite) documentation.

Then right-click the request and selected "Send to Intruder".

In the Positions tab within Intruder, first click "Clear" then select the section you want to vary, and click "Add"

In the Payloads tab select the Payload type as "Numbers" and configure the range.

Click "Start attack"

For more information, consult the [documentation](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/intruder_using).

Answer (score 0):

One Another solution is that you can use Counter in jmeter. That you can find from below path
Thread Group > configElement > Counter.

1. Configure the Counter as per your need.
2. Give the Reference Name i for counter.
3. Use the variable in your request

For more information.

[image: CounterForIncrementID]